# Addthis pinterest bug after image selection

Tags: wordpress, addthis, pinterest

The Pinterest button is not working anymore on my wordpress blog.
After selection of the image to publish ADDTHIS show me a list of services and no PINTEREST in that.
Nobody encounter this problem.
http://www.moowon.com
I also checked on ADDTHIS website and I got the same bug when I click on pinterest button in the example:
https://www.addthis.com/get/sharing?frm=hp#.UFBckESitL8

Here is my code

```
    <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" addthis:url="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" addthis:title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
            <a class="addthis_button_tweet" tw:via="metwit"></a>
            <a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit" pi:pinit:layout="horizontal" pi:pinit:description="<?php the_title(); ?>"></a>
            <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};      </script>
        <!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

Any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I wrote to addthis.com's support yesterday. It seems that the issue is fixed now without having to change any of my code.

Comment: Yes just working fine today. This addthis bug was temporary.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, its working 100%

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};      </script>
```

Comment: THank you for your help. I make progress.  In fact pinterest is behind: <a class="addthis_button_preferred_7"></a> I also added my code in the first post above because I want the non compact version of the buttons.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code fr sharing if your ADD THIS is not working...

```
<span class="st_twitter_large" displayText="Tweet"></span>
<span class="st_facebook_large" displayText="Facebook"></span>
<span class="st_ybuzz_large" displayText="Yahoo! Buzz"></span>
<span class="st_gbuzz_large" displayText="Pinterest"></span>
<span class="st_email_large" displayText="Email"></span>
<span class="st_sharethis_large" displayText="ShareThis"></span>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    stLight.options({publisher:'12345'});
 </script>
```

Comment: I am talking about addthis not sharethis!

Comment: Ok no problem at all, use this code, i use this code in my site, 100% working...